# how to set values between worksheets after IF statement using 2 last rows

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I am trying to copy and paste the entire entire columns values from sheet named Hey, to another columns in a sheet named final.

I dont want to use copy, paste or select option.However, my code is copying only the 1st line.

```
IntLastRow = Sheets("Hey").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
' IntRLastRow = Sheets("Interdiction Review").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If Sheets("Hey").Range("H2") = "" Then
    Sheets("Final").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Hey").Range("G2:G" & IntLastRow).Value
ElseIf Sheets("Hey").Range("H2") <> "" Then
    Sheets("Final").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Hey").Range("H2:H" & IntLastRow).Value
EndIf
```

maybe do you know what I am doing wrong?

I need to copy dates from 2 or more columns to another column located in a different worksheet.

However, I am not sure if I can use 2 last row in the same line.
I am trying this code, but only paste the value of 1 line.

```
intrlastrow = Sheets("Final").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
 Debug.Print intrlastrow
    If Sheets("Hey").Range("AJ2") = "" Then
            Sheets("Final").Range("A" & intrlastrow, "A" & IntLastRow).Value = Sheets("Hey").Range("AI2:AI" & IntLastRow).Value
        ElseIf Sheets("Hey").Range("AJ2") <> "" Then
            Sheets("Final").Range("A" & intrlastrow, "A" & IntLastRow).Value = Sheets("Hey").Range("AJ2:AJ" & IntLastRow).Value
        End If
```

I need to add the values of 2 or more columns from sheet named HEY to the same column in the destination sheet (Final sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the range you are trying insert the values from is as large as the one you are taking them from, only the data which fits will be copied. Changing your code to something like

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim IntLastRow As Long
    
    IntLastRow = Sheets("Hey").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' IntRLastRow = Sheets("Interdiction Review").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Sheets("Hey").Range("H2") = "" Then
        Sheets("Final").Range("A2:A" & IntLastRow).Value = Sheets("Hey").Range("G2:G" & IntLastRow).Value
    ElseIf Sheets("Hey").Range("H2") <> "" Then
        Sheets("Final").Range("A2:A" & IntLastRow).Value = Sheets("Hey").Range("H2:H" & IntLastRow).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

should do the trick.

You probably notice that I've changed `Sheets("Final").Range("A2")` to `Sheets("Final").Range("A2:A" & IntLastRow)`, similar to what you've done to decide what range to copy values from.

Comment: I feel so silly, basic I was supposed to use the same **IntLastRow** on destination sheet. Thank you. It is working.